# Verifying self-signed certificate error while configuration between gitlab and keycloak

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, openid-connect, self-signed-certificate

I'm working on a project on a vm ubuntu server. I'm trying to sign in my gitlab instance with keycloak. I did some configuration on gitlab.rb file as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvu6D.png)

the gitlab instance url: https://192.168.56.103 the keycloak url: https://192.168.56.103:8085

at the gitlab sign in page I see the sign in with keycloak button. But when ı click on it I see this error on the screen : Could not authenticate you from OpenIDConnect because "Ssl connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)".

can you help me with that, please

I checked the IP adresses, I checked paths, I checked the certificate, I even created a new one but ıt dıd not work. I'm still getting the same error.